# Conversion of String to Currency Data Type

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2005, insert, sql

I have a hard time finding a solutions for my problem, I am creating a program in Visual Studio (Visual Basic Windows Form Application) and SQL SERVER 2005 as my BACK END, one of my column there has a `money` (datatype), I don't know how to apply the right `SELECT` STATEMENT for my `INSERT` (button).

Could anyone tell me how to cast a conversion in this?

Comment: Please explain if you need this in SQL or VB.NET?

Comment: actually in VB(WindowsFormApplication) not in VB.NET

Comment: I want to Insert a Data into my DB in SQLSERVER but the problem is VB10 don't allow me to do that, it said I had to cast a conversion first...

Comment: VB6? Not VB.NET? What version of Visual Studio?

Comment: but it's a windows form application , not vb.net

Comment: I am afraid to say you are mistaken. The answer you have been given is in VB.NET, not VB6.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Dim price As Single = Single.Parse(txtprice.Text)
txtPrice.Text = String.Format("{0:C}", price)
```